# Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter accepting wrong LDAP query in the System.Management.Automation library (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core

I'm using the `System.Management.Automation` library to extract users from an AD in my application. Which users are extracted is done by specifying the LDAP query in `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter`, but first I validate the LDAP query to make sure it is valid like this:

```
public static bool ValidLDAPQuery(string ldapQuery)
{
    try
    {
        using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var adUsersList = powerShell
                 .AddCommand("Get-ADUser")
                 .AddParameter("LDAPFilter", ldapQuery)
                 .Invoke();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The thing is that wrong LDAP queries passed to this method are accepted in normal PowerShell. For instance this query `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!BLABLABLAObject=*))` would work, but of course the return count would just be `0`. It only throws an error if the parenthesis is uneven or when the `Key=Value` search is not written properly.

Is there a way to make it throw an error if any part of the query is wrong (not taking into account parenthesis and equal signs)?

Comment: So your actual question is really: "How do I validate whether an AD LDAP query is valid?" The usual way is to run the query, and the server will return an error if it's not valid.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart but that´s the thing when I run the above query, it´s valid. Shouldn´t it give an error at (!BLABLABLAObject=*) ? even if I mess with the objectClass and ObjectCategory names the query still runs, without no results of course

Comment: IIRC an LDAP query doesn't validate whether attributes exist.

Comment: I see, how would you go about validating it then?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? The LDAP server doesn't reject queries asking for results with attributes that don't exist; it simply returns no results (that's not an error condition). This is similar to when you use a `Where-Object` filter for a non-existent property in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bill_Stewart for the clarification. I'll just write the clarification he wrote in the comments above as an answer just in case it goes unnoticed.

So the command will throw an error when a wrongly written LDAP query is passed to the method parameter, such as `(&(objectClass=user objectCategory=person)(!CriticalObject=*`. But it will not reject the query if the attributes or values specified do not exist, `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!BLABLABLAObject=*))` for instance, it will simply yield not results.